# Removing free form text from one cell to another

Tags: excel

I have 2 cells in excel and I want to remove free form text from another cell if it exists in another. For example:

- Column C2 says "Great Escapes 1122 Apple St"
- Column D2 says  "Great Escapes"

I want a new cell to result in "1122 Apple St"

Comment: Will your `C2` *always* start with the text to remove, as given in `D2`? Or could `C2` be "Apartment Great Escapes 1122 Apple St." and you have "Great Escapes" in `D2`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `Substitute()`:

`=Substitute(C2,D2,"",1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try what I have below. just change the formula to fit your cells.
[image]